# Как в React добавить версию к файлу или хэш?

Tags: reactjs

Дорабатываю React-приложение, выкатываю на продакшен, а обновления не подтягиваются. Видимо браузер все кэширует. Как сделать так, чтобы при добавлении обновлений новые js-файлы заново подтягивались.

Раньше видел такое, когда Vue.js изучал, что хэш добавляют или версию файла, чтобы решить данную проблему.

Можете подсказать как это можно реализовать в React?

**Update:** посмотрел сейчас папку `build` в принципе приложение развернутое через `creare-react-app` подставляет к названию js-файла дополнительное название `main.9fd5dd5c.js` но по какой-то причине, на стороне клиента все равно все файлы старые.

Comment: Правильно заметил, create-react-app сам добавляет хеш. Поэтому проблема не в хеше, а в чем то другом. CDN? Проверь какие файлы запрашивает с продакшн. Если старые то наверное это закешированный index.html

Comment: заметили, что на продакшене не отрабатывал `service-worker.js`, просто подгружался `index.html`. Поправили с коллегой роуты, пока ждем когда будет следующий деплой, чтобы проверить сработало ли решение